# Circular Scrollable layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to code for a circular scrollable layout.(see attached image). I am wondering, which layout i can use to achieve this? Please suggest some approach or links.

cheers...[image]

Comment: May I ask from which App this screenshot was taken from?

Comment: this screen shot is not from any app. Its just a client requirement Ahmad.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something similar to what you are looking for. Its an android implimentation of the round Path-App menu:

https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu - Apache 2.0

https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/ - LGPL

It should look something like the menu in the left corner:
[image: path]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using layout at all.

Use [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) instead.

SurfaceView is very easy to use. See the official Lunar Lander [code example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/LunarLander/index.html). To see SurfaceView in action.

Comment: can i get onClickListeners or touchListeners on buttons/images drawn in surface view.

Comment: You receive onTouch events with parameters: x,y, up/down/drag and you need to manage yourself which image is pressed, and draw the proper image in its location, draw a different icon for "pressed" state, etc.

Comment: why -1? It *is* the best approach IMO. Please explain, or whoever did this is a troll

Comment: Don't get it eather this was the only useful so far... Fixed that @uval