# Horizontal Curved Sliding menu

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

In my app i want to achieve some thing like this

[image]

I have tried a lot of libraries which provide a circular layout for example like this one:-
https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

You can check the code for circlelayout there , not posting here as its too big.

I have also tried Circular List view as discussed in here:-
[Circular ListView (Items on Half Circle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253295/circular-listview-items-on-half-circle)

But with both the approach i am able to achieve something like this :-

[image]

This looks something like Ferris wheel but its not what i want , where the elements are connected to each other and the scrolling is smooth.

Comment: how you achieve this can you share the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with https://github.com/xresco/CircularLayout and [Circular Scrollable layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912916/circular-scrollable-layout)

**A scrollable circular layout** for android where you can add items, customize the radius, the number of items displayed at a time and the X and Y offset of the layout.

Moreover, you can **control how the items are rendered when scrolling the layout**.

**There are two modes Pinned and Fixed**. The two modes differ in the way the items rotate. Here are the samples:

[image]

Comment: Thanks , it did help me a lot . I am facing another issue now , however it is best left for an another question. Check this out   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649137/semi-circular-menu-with-elements-facing-towards-center

Answer (score 1):

you can try this 
https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu/

or

https://github.com/Andrew0000/Circular-Layout

I wish anyone of 2 that will help you.